# Resizing background-color of font in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have CSS in place that sets the span of text color in white and the background in red using `Brandon Text` as a font. Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="headline">
    <span>Long Headline Wrapping Around</span>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS file

```
.headline {
    color: white;
}

.headline span {
    font-family: 'Brandon Text', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700px;
    line-height: 56px;
    background-color: #DD3300;
}
```

But the background size is too thick. Is there a way to resize it? Line-height is mainly for the spacing between text but is not related to the size of the background itself. I'm guessing that it has more to do with how much space the Brandon Text font takes (I don't know the term for that) than with CSS's ability to resize the background.

EDIT: King Kong's answer was great, but now I have an additional complication. I was also using box-shadow, so the CSS for `.headline span` above is more like:

```
.headline span {
    font-family: 'Brandon Text', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700px;
    line-height: 56px;
    background-color: #DD3300;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    box-shadow: 12px 0 0 #DD3300, -12px 0 0 #DD3300;
}
```

Comment: Check margins and padding?

Comment: Background-size is too thick, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach is try using `box-shadow` with shadow color `white` (theoretically the same with the parent background color):

```
.headline span {
  ...
  box-shadow:0 3px 0 0 white inset,
  0 -3px 0 0 white inset;
}
```

### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/4zF2A/)

The second approach (which I think is better) is to use `linear-gradient` background for your element:

```
.headline span {
  ...
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 10%, #DD3300 10%, #DD3300 90%, transparent 90%);
}
```

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4zF2A/1)

Use linear-gradient background with setting background-size and background-position:

```
.headline span {
   ...
   background: linear-gradient(#DD3300, #DD3300) no-repeat;
   background-position:center;
   background-size:100% 90%;
 }
```

Note that you can use `calc(100% - 3px)` for the height part of `background-size`. Although `calc` is not supported in some old versions of ***IE*** and ***Opeara***, see [calc() supports](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

### [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/4zF2A/2/)

As you can see the demo 2 and demo 3 use relative offset to shrink the background's height. Only the first demo uses `px`, here is another demo uses `px` but it requires browsers to support multi-backgrounds feature (all the current browsers support this feature, only some old versions of ***IE*** don't, requires IE9+, see [CSS3 Multi-background support](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds)):

```
.headline span {
  ...
  background: linear-gradient(#DD3300, #DD3300) no-repeat,
              linear-gradient(#DD3300, #DD3300) no-repeat;
  background-position:left top 3px, left bottom 3px;
  background-size:100% 50%;
}
```

### [Demo 4.](http://jsfiddle.net/4zF2A/3/)

Comment: Your answer was helpful. I have been able to use Demo 2 with linear gradient to reduce the top and bottom of the background text. Unfortunately, since I am also using box-shadow to add a "padding" to lines of text similar to here http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/ The result is a kind of barbell look with the box shadow being the bells. Can I also reduce the box shadow height?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for     `padding:10px;`

[image]